# How to modify or extend standard socket class in Python?

Tags: python, sockets

I am beginner in programming and trying to develop simple console messenger on Python. I have an idea to extend standard socket.socket object and add to it additional attribute "account_name". I created new class "NamedSoket" based on standard socket class. Here is my code:

```
class NamedSocket(socket):

def __init__(self, family=-1, type=-1, proto=-1, fileno=None, name=None):
    super().__init__(family=-1, type=-1, proto=-1, fileno=None)
    self.name = name

def accept(self):        
    fd, addr = self._accept()
    sock = NamedSocket(self.family, self.type, self.proto, fileno=fd, name=self.name)       
    if getdefaulttimeout() is None and self.gettimeout():
        sock.setblocking(True)
    return sock, addr

server = NamedSocket()
server.bind(('', 8000))
server.listen()

client = NamedSocket('Bob')
client.connect(('localhost', 8000))

new_client, address = server.accept()
```

Although new socket objects are created successfully, they do not work properly.. Methods 'recv' and 'send' do not work.. Could you please explain to me, where is the problem?

P.S.: I understand, that my 'idea', maybe, is not good 'at all', but now I became very interested in 'inheritance issue'. From first look, it should work, but it does not...

Comment: _Methods 'recv' and 'send' do not work_ Can you be more specific? I believe the indentation of the code in your post is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've replicated described actions as accurate as possible. This code is working without any error.

```
import socket as sk

class NamedSocket(sk.socket):

    def __init__(self, family=sk.AF_INET, type=sk.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, fileno=None, name=None):
        super().__init__(family, type, proto, fileno)
        self.name = name

    def accept(self):
        fd, addr = self._accept()
        sock = NamedSocket(self.family, self.type, self.proto, fileno=fd, name=self.name)
        if sk.getdefaulttimeout() is None and self.gettimeout():
            sock.setblocking(True)
        return sock, addr

server = NamedSocket()
server.bind(('', 8000))
server.listen()

client = NamedSocket(name='Bob')
client.connect(('localhost', 8000))

new_client, address = server.accept()
client.send('hello'.encode())
new_client.recv(1024)
```

I replaced default parameters in `__init()__` method of `NamedSocket` class to `AF_INET`, `SOCK_STREAM` and `0` for the first three arguments. Running such script does not imply any error. You could try do the same changes or edit something related to IP address binded to socket being established on the server side, according to error message.

Comment: Thank you very much for so detailed explanation, Kost!  Now this works!

Comment: It's great to see someone's solving their problems!

Answer (score 0):

As you may see, your constructor method takes a bunch of optional parameters:

```
def __init__(self, family=-1, type=-1, proto=-1, fileno=None, name=None):
    super().__init__(family=-1, type=-1, proto=-1, fileno=None)
    self.name = name
```

When you try to create an object of class `NamedSocket` for client, you pass the only 'Bob' parameter, which, by precedence of function argument, will be passed to `family` argument, but not to `name`. For doing things in the key you want, you may write:

```
client = NamedSocket(name='Bob')
```

Comment: Thank you, Kost! Of cause, it is dumb mistake of mine. I've correct it and now I can send some data, using `client.send('hello'.encode())`. But now I have a mistake on server side, when use command `new_client.recv(1024)`: **OSError: [WinError 10057] Запрос на отправку или получение данных  (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.**  Could you please advise, what is the problem now?

Comment: I have tried to do the same things. Please see my second answer.